# D3.JS- cant get rid of padding using .rangeRoundBands()

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a bar chart using the .rangeRoundBands method. I'm trying to figure out how to get rid of the padding on the outside of the bars so that the bars go to the edge of the X axis.

Here is my x scale that is used in my x axis:

```
xScaleOrdinal = d3.scale.ordinal();

xScaleOrdinal
        .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1)
        .domain(thedata.map(function(d) { return d.date; }));
```

This is how the chart looks now:

[image]

Comment: The outer padding is the third argument to `.rangeRoundBands()`, see [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#ordinal_rangeRoundBands).

Comment: @LarsKotthoff that's not the solution. Even setting this to zero gives you outer margins when you have large number of bars. I'm curious if anyone has a solution because I've seen this myself.

Comment: Could you make a reproducible example please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nature of `.rangeRoundBands()` is such that it cannot guarantee padding settings, since it rounds the groups to pixel coordinates.   Generally, if there are a lot of bars being displayed in a small-ish area, things can get funky.

You can solve this by extending the pixel area you are plotting the bars in, or by simply using `rangeBands()` instead of `rangeRoundBands()`.

Comment: Thanks, rangeBands seemed to work:    xScaleOrdinal.rangeBands([0, width], .1,0)

Answer (score 0):

The `.rangeRoundBands()` function takes a third argument, which specifies the outer padding (padding around the bands as opposed to the one between them). So might be worth to set that specifically to 0 and see whether that solves you issue.

Your x axis code would then look like this

```
xScaleOrdinal = d3.scale.ordinal();

xScaleOrdinal
        .rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0.1, 0)
        .domain(thedata.map(function(d) { return d.date; }));
```